# Maximum length of linked list in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to compare the time it takes to perform four operations on an array compared to the same operations on a list. How do I find the max value of the length of an array or linked list, where I only have to find the value of the shorter one because to compare the time the number of elements has to be equal. So my question is 1. do linked lists have a max number because I know arrays are just Integer.MAX_INTEGER. And 2. what is this max number because I have to do multiple tests with of equal numbers of elements with exact spacing between the number. Here's my code if that matters.

```
private static class Node{
 private String string;
 private Node next;
 public Node(String e, Node n){
 string=e;
 next=n;
   }
 public String getElement(){return string;}
 public Node getNext(){return next;}
public void setNext(Node n){next=n;}
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to attempting to create the largest array or largest linked list -- and possibly failing -- you could measure other sizes, and plot a curve.

Answer (score 2):

Max # of linked array depends on the memory size. For Java you can take a look at the JVM mem size to figure that out. The space usage for both link list and array is the same. The only difference is that Array requires continues memory allocation and linked list doesn't. So generally speaking link list should always have a bigger size cap than array. (If the memory is not allocated at all then both has the same max cap)

Comment: But would this always be bigger than the max length of an array?

Comment: @trosy Think about it this way....array has a max size because of the limitation of int. theoretically it could have infinite size , I.E. create a List, fill it with > max int number of values and convert back to array. And linked list doesn't have this restriction